# Custom Maven plugin hosting and prefix resolution

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, archiva

I've wrote my own custom `Maven` plugin and uploaded it to my `Archiva` server. It works fine with the full name specified:

```
mvn com.mjolnirr:maven-plugin:manifest
```

But when I want to do it via the prefix, it fails:

```
mvn mjolnirr:manifest

[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'mjolnirr' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/home/sk_/.m2/repository), mjolnirr (http://mjolnirr.dyndns.org/archiva/repository/plugins), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
```

My plugin's `pom`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mjolnirr</groupId>
<artifactId>mjolnirr-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>0.2</version>
<packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>

<name>Mjolnirr Maven Plugin</name>

<url>http://mjolnirr.com</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>mjolnirr</id>
        <name>Mjolnirr snapshot repository</name>
        <url>http://mjolnirr.com/archiva/repository/snapshots</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>mjolnirr</id>
        <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
        <url>http://mjolnirr.com/archiva/repository/snapshots</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
        <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- For superclass resolving -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mjolnirr</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- For XML producing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.5</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <goalPrefix>mjolnirr</goalPrefix>
                <skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>true</skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>mojo-descriptor</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>descriptor</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>help-goal</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>helpmojo</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>run-its</id>
        <build>

            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-invoker-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <debug>true</debug>
                        <cloneProjectsTo>${project.build.directory}/it</cloneProjectsTo>
                        <pomIncludes>
                            <pomInclude>*/pom.xml</pomInclude>
                        </pomIncludes>
                        <postBuildHookScript>verify</postBuildHookScript>
                        <localRepositoryPath>${project.build.directory}/local-repo</localRepositoryPath>
                        <settingsFile>src/it/settings.xml</settingsFile>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>integration-test</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>install</goal>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>

        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
</project>
```

It looks like I have to put some definition into my repository. Can you help me?

**ADD** I've discovered that maven trying to download `maven-metadata.xml` from `org/apache/maven/plugins`. Is it possible to change this path in the project POM, without changing the maven settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only plugins with a groupId of `org.apache.maven.plugins` will be searched by default.

To get Maven to search additional groupIds for plugins, additional plugin groups can be configured in each user's settings.xml file, e.g.:

```
<pluginGroups>
    <pluginGroup>org.mortbay.jetty</pluginGroup>
    <pluginGroup>org.apache.tomcat.maven</pluginGroup>
</pluginGroups>
```

More information on this in the [Maven plugin guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html#Configuring_Maven_to_Search_for_Plugins).

Comment: Hmm, I use Maven JavaFX plugin, and I'm able to run `mvn jfx:run`, but doesn't have the groupId you've mentioned.

Comment: @skayred `jfx:run` does not work for me.  Its group ID is definitely not defined in `settings.xml`?

Comment: same for me, but those guys got the prefix working in the project with special pom.xml - http://zenjava.com/javafx/maven/plugin-info.html

Comment: Yep, I're right - you can use prefix after first use fully-specified name